# Is there a drawImage method that doesn't auto scale?

Tags: java, graphics, render, resolution, drawimage

I just want to draw an image, within a set range of width, height, that instead of scaling just omits the extra part of the image that doesn't fit within that box.

```
g.drawImage(img, 3, 106, bgST.getWidth()-700, bgST.getHeight()-700, null);
```

Basically this, but without the autoscaling

Comment: If you're using a BufferedImage, you can get a subImage

Comment: Sure, you don't want to scale the image? then use as mentioned by @MadProgrammer.

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer, that solved it!

Comment: Note that `getSubImage` on a `BufferedImage` may degrade performance noticably. I'd recommend using the famous `drawImage` method that allows you to specify the source- and destination rectangles: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29 (Note that it says that it scales on the fly, it will of course **not** have to scale when the source and target are of equal size - you have all the freedom by chosing the parameters appropriately)

Answer (score 0):

AS @MadProgrammer suggested, use the subimage method of the BufferedImage class.